# How do i install OpenEMM on CentOS 5.9

Tags: mysql, centos, python

Hi i am trying to install OpenMM on my CentOS 5.9 remotely via ssh (PuTTY) based on the step mentioned [here](http://www.roothelp.net/install-openemm-on-centos-6-x/) (Yes i know the guide is for CentOS 6.x).

However when i try to do:

```
yum install mysql-server MySQL-python
```

it says:

No package mysql-server available.

```
Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: MySQL-python
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) for package: MySQL-python
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.1.c1.el5.x86_64 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.1.c1.el5.x86_64 (base)
MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.1.c1.el5.x86_64 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.1.c1.el5.x86_64 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.1.c1.el5.x86_64 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.1.c1.el5.x86_64 (base)
```

I already have MySQL installed on my server, and it is already serving few application. I think i do not need this package. However i am not sure how to resolve the missing dependencies for MySQL-python.

#### EDIT BIT

```
output of yum list installed | grep mysql
root@xxxxxxxx [/home/temp]# yum list installed |grep mysql
cpanel-mysql.x86_64                             5.0.96-1.cp1136        installed
cpanel-mysql-libs.x86_64                        5.0.96-1.cp1136        installed
cpanel-perl-514-DBD-mysql.x86_64                4.021-1.cp1136         installed
root@xxxxxxx [/home/temp]#
```

#### END OF EDIT

Comment: Could you show output of the # yum list installed | grep mysql

Comment: @ALex_hha output is as shown on the edit bit part.

Comment: You have cPanel packages installed. Contact cPanel support for assistance.

Comment: try the following "# rpm -ql cpanel-mysql | grep libmysqlclient_r.so.15" and "# rpm -ql cpanel-mysql-libs | grep libmysqlclient_r.so.15"

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to install mysql

```
# yum provides "*/libmysqlclient_r.so.15"

mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9.i386 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries.
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15

# yum install mysql MySQL-python
```

Comment: is it gonna cause any conflict(s) with my existing mysql?

Comment: i still have no luck on the installation. It still gives me the same exact message. Thx for helping though...

Comment: As I can see you are using cpanel (I don't like it), I think you should try to install mysql-python via cpanel web interface

Comment: i'll try that instead.